# optim in R failing due to NAs

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I have been trying to estimate a rather messy nonlinear regression model in R for quite some time now. After countless failed attempts using the `nls` function, I am now trying my luck with `optim`, which I have used many times in the past. For this example, I'll use the following data:

```
x1 <- runif(1000,0,7)
x2 <- runif(1000,0,7)
x3 <- runif(1000,0,7)

y <- log(.5 + .5*x1 + .7*x2 + .4*x3 + .05*x1^2 + .1*x2^2 + .15*x3^2 - .05*x1*x2 - .1*x1*x3 - .07*x2*x3 + .02*x1*x2*x2) + rnorm(1000)
```

I would like to estimate the parameters in the polynomial expression inside the log() function above, and so I have defined the following function to replicate a nonlinear least squares regression:

```
g <- function(coefs){

    fitted <- coefs[1] + coefs[2]*x1 + coefs[3]*x2 + coefs[4]*x3 + coefs[5]*x1^2 + coefs[6]*x2^2 + coefs[7]*x3^2 + coefs[8]*x1*x2 + coefs[9]*x1*x3 + coefs[10]*x2*x3 + coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3       
    error <- y - log(fitted)
    return(sum(error^2))
}
```

In order to avoid negative starting values inside the log() expression, I first estimate the linear model below:

```
lm.1 <- lm(I(exp(y)) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x1*x2) + I(x1*x3) + I(x2*x3) + I(x1*x2*x3))
intercept.start <- ifelse((min(fitted(lm.1)-lm.1$coefficients[1])) <= 0, -(min(fitted(lm.1)-lm.1$coefficients[1])) + .5, .5)
coefs.start <- c(intercept.start,lm.1$coefficients[-1])
```

Defining `intercept.start` above guarantees that the expression inside of log() will be strictly positive at the outset. However, when I run the `optim` command

```
nl.model <- optim(coefs.start, g, method="L-BFGS-B")
```

I get the following error message

```
Error in optim(coefs.start, g, method = "L-BFGS-B") : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
In addition: Warning message:
In log(fitted) : NaNs produced
```

Does anyone know how I can force the `optim` routine to simply disregard parameter estimates that would produce negative values inside of the log() expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not defined the `ifelse` to return .5 for only strictly positive results, only to return it for non-negative results. You could still get zeros.

Comment: @BondedDust Good observation, and thanks a lot for the comment, but this isn't what is creating the problem since I still get the error message when < is changed to <= in the ifelse() statement. Anyway, I have edited my question in response to your comment.

Comment: The last term in your definition of `y` is: `.02*x1*x2*x2`. The last term in your model function is: `coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach.

Aside from the typo mentioned in the comment, if the issue is that the argument to the `log(...)` is < 0 for certain parameter estimates, you can change the function definition to prevent that.

```
# just some setup - we'll need this later
set.seed(1)
err <- rnorm(1000, sd=0.1)    # note smaller error sd
x1  <- runif(1000,0,7)
x2  <- runif(1000,0,7)
x3  <- runif(1000,0,7)
par <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, -0.05, -0.1, -0.07, 0.02)
m   <- cbind(1, x1, x2, x3, x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x1*x2, x1*x3, x2*x3, x1*x2*x3)
y  <- as.numeric(log(m %*% par)) + err
# note slight change in the model function definition
g <- function(coefs){
  fitted <- coefs[1] + coefs[2]*x1 + coefs[3]*x2 + coefs[4]*x3 + coefs[5]*x1^2 + coefs[6]*x2^2 + coefs[7]*x3^2 + coefs[8]*x1*x2 + coefs[9]*x1*x3 + coefs[10]*x2*x3 + coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3
  fitted <- ifelse(fitted<=0, 1, fitted)   # ensures fitted > 0
  error  <- y - log(fitted)
  return(sum(error^2))
}
lm.1 <- lm(I(exp(y)) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x1*x2) + I(x1*x3) + I(x2*x3) + I(x1*x2*x3))
nl.model <- optim(coef(lm.1), g, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(maxit=1000))
nl.model$par
#     (Intercept)              x1              x2              x3         I(x1^2)         I(x2^2)         I(x3^2)      I(x1 * x2)      I(x1 * x3)      I(x2 * x3) I(x1 * x2 * x3) 
#      0.40453182      0.50136222      0.71696293      0.45335893      0.05461253      0.10210854      0.14913914     -0.06169715     -0.11195476     -0.08497180      0.02531717 
with(nl.model, cat(convergence, message))
# 0 CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH
```

Note that these estimates are pretty close to the actual values. That's because in the setup I used a smaller error term (sd = 0.2 instead of 1). In your example, the error is large compared to the response (`y`), so you're basically fitting random error.

If you fit the model using the actual parameter values as starting estimates, you get nearly identical results, no closer to the "true" values.

```
nl.model <- optim(par, g,  method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(maxit=1000))
nl.model$par
#  [1]  0.40222956  0.50159930  0.71734810  0.45459606  0.05465654  0.10206887  0.14899640 -0.06177640 -0.11209065 -0.08497423  0.02533085
with(nl.model, cat(convergence, message))
# 0 CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH
```

Try this with the original error (sd = 1) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comment. The problem that I am now discovering with both of the solutions provided in this thread is that they yield parameter estimates that might produce some negative and/or zero values inside of the log() expression when fitted values are taken later on. This makes it impossible to obtain the residuals for the model, which I also need to do. Ideally, there would be some way to minimize the squared error subject to the restriction that the parameter estimates cannot yield any negative/zero fitted values inside of the log() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a log of my efforts to investigate. I put a maximum on the fitted values and got convergence. I then asked myself if increasing that max would do anything th the estimated parameters and found that there was no change... AND there was no difference from the starting values, so I think you messed up in building the function. Perhaps you can investigate further:

```
> gp <- function(coefs){
+ 
+     fitted <- coefs[1] + coefs[2]*x1 + coefs[3]*x2 + coefs[4]*x3 + coefs[5]*x1^2 + coefs[6]*x2^2 + coefs[7]*x3^2 + coefs[8]*x1*x2 + coefs[9]*x1*x3 + coefs[10]*x2*x3 + coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3   }
> describe( gp( coefs.start) )   #describe is from pkg:Hmisc
gp(coefs.start) 
      n missing  unique    Info    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75 
   1000       0    1000       1   13.99   2.953   4.692   8.417  12.475  18.478 
    .90     .95 
 25.476  28.183 

lowest :  0.5000  0.5228  0.5684  0.9235  1.1487
highest: 41.0125 42.6003 43.1457 43.5950 47.2234 
> g <- function(coefs){
+ 
+     fitted <- max( coefs[1] + coefs[2]*x1 + coefs[3]*x2 + coefs[4]*x3 + coefs[5]*x1^2 + coefs[6]*x2^2 + coefs[7]*x3^2 + coefs[8]*x1*x2 + coefs[9]*x1*x3 + coefs[10]*x2*x3 + coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3     , 1000)
+     error <- y - log(fitted)
+     return(sum(error^2))
+ }
> nl.model <- optim(coefs.start, g, method="L-BFGS-B")
> nl.model
$par
                             x1              x2              x3         I(x1^2) 
     0.77811231     -0.94586233     -1.33540959      1.65454871      0.31537594 
        I(x2^2)         I(x3^2)      I(x1 * x2)      I(x1 * x3)      I(x2 * x3) 
     0.45717138      0.11051418      0.59197115     -0.25800792      0.04931727 
I(x1 * x2 * x3) 
    -0.08124126 

$value
[1] 24178.62

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"

> g <- function(coefs){
+ 
+     fitted <- max( coefs[1] + coefs[2]*x1 + coefs[3]*x2 + coefs[4]*x3 + coefs[5]*x1^2 + coefs[6]*x2^2 + coefs[7]*x3^2 + coefs[8]*x1*x2 + coefs[9]*x1*x3 + coefs[10]*x2*x3 + coefs[11]*x1*x2*x3     , 100000)
+     error <- y - log(fitted)
+     return(sum(error^2))
+ }
> nl.model <- optim(coefs.start, g, method="L-BFGS-B")
> nl.model
$par
                             x1              x2              x3         I(x1^2) 
     0.77811231     -0.94586233     -1.33540959      1.65454871      0.31537594 
        I(x2^2)         I(x3^2)      I(x1 * x2)      I(x1 * x3)      I(x2 * x3) 
     0.45717138      0.11051418      0.59197115     -0.25800792      0.04931727 
I(x1 * x2 * x3) 
    -0.08124126 

$value
[1] 89493.99

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

.

Comment: The problem that I am now discovering with both of the solutions provided in this thread is that they yield parameter estimates that might produce some negative and/or zero values inside of the log() expression when fitted values are taken later on. This makes it impossible to obtain the residuals for the model, which I also need to do. Ideally, there would be some way to minimize the squared error subject to the restriction that the parameter estimates cannot yield any negative/zero fitted values inside of the log() function.

Comment: Right, it's fair to say that optimization is a bitch.

Comment: Also fair to say that you may need to explore some other functions.